# SQL query to count and then sort the count in ascending order

Tags: sql, count

I have a SQL query to count the number of rating with at least 15 records and then order them by average rating.

So here is what I came up with:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(rate) FROM RateTable
WHERE rating = 5
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(rate) > 15
ORDER BY AVG(rate) ASC;
```

It did actually filtered those product with less than 15 records, however the results is not sorted in order. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

name           Count(rate)      AVG(rate)
product1       20               5
product2       18               5
product3       17               5

Comment: I see it's pretty standard SQL, but however you'd better tell us what RDBMS you are working on. A minimal,  simple,  complete example would also help.

Comment: At first glance I don't see anything wrong in this query.  Can you show us the actual outcome?

Comment: Sorry as I am quite new so I am forbidden to post image. My results are: product1 20, product2 15, product3 18, product4 17. I am using MSSQL

Comment: It's better you don't post images.  You can take this data (formatted) and add it to the original question.

Comment: Ok..  But what you show is the count,  not the average. How do you know it's not the correct order?

Comment: You'd better show in the output also the average rate and see if the result is OK for you.

Comment: Okay sorry my concept might be wrong. So what I need to do is first count if their rating records are > 15 rows and then sort them by their average rating. I printed out the AVG and all I get is 5 only. Is that supposed to be that way?

Comment: @Insac Any ideas?

Comment: Show some data of the RateTable (name,  rate,  rating) and the query you're now testing.  It sounds like rate=rating.

Comment: @Insac Hello, after hours of trying and I can't still figure out what went wrong. I have updated my answer. Hope you can look into it. But just to check with you because I am retrieving those rate which is 5 only, so even if I AVG it, no matter how much records I have for that specific product, it will still return 5 right? because that's what I get

Comment: I thought initially that rating and rate were two different fields.  If they have always equal value,  then yes,  the average rate of all the records with rate=5 will be 5. In this case the order is meaningless.

Comment: I see. That solves my problem. I think it is a tricky question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT name, COUNT(rate), AVG(rate) as Rate FROM RateTable
    WHERE rating = 5
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(rate) > 15
) as Result ORDER BY Rate ASC
```

Comment: It showed me incorrect syntax at 'Result', expecting ID or quoted_ID.

Comment: Yeah, there is red error lines underneath. I am using MSSQL by the way

Comment: Sorry, but the OP said he wants the result ordered by Average rating.  You are sorting by count.

Comment: @Insac your edit should have been rather another answer or a comment to the this post, not an edit.

Comment: Ah I though you are using mysql sorry

Comment: @NewbeeDev Hmm even if I removed the quotes, the red line error still at the Result there saying no specific column

Comment: @WhoamI what's the error? try changing the Rate.Rate to Rate I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

May be this is due to the improper use of aggregate function in ORDER BY clause, there are certain limitations. The following link may help you...
[What can an aggregate function do in the ORDER BY clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099282/what-can-an-aggregate-function-do-in-the-order-by-clause)

Best of luck.