# Sorting a Flask-SQLAlchemy model query by the count of child rows in one-to-many?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a **Product** Model:

```
class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'product'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    offers = db.relationship('Offer', back_populates='product', lazy=True)
```

and a **Offer** Model:

```
class Offer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'offer'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'), nullable=False)
    product = db.relationship('Product', back_populates='offers')
```

I would like to know how can I order a list of **Products** by the **amount of offers** each product has. I would like to be able to do something like:

```
sort = request.args.get('sort') # asc / desc
products = Product.query.order_by(len(Product.offers).sort).pagination([...])
```

I tried doing this but it only returns one Product:

```
query = db.session.query(Product).join(Product.offers)
if order == 'desc':
    query = query.order_by(desc(func.count(Product.offers)))
else:
    query = query.order_by(func.count(Product.offers))
query = query.filter(Product.has_offers == True)
products = query.paginate(page=page, per_page=50)
```

I will use this to be able to sort a HTML table by clicking on the table header. I am also sorting through other informations:

```
sort_by = dict(id=Product.id, mp_id=Product.marketplace_id,
                   updated=Product.last_seen, name=Product.name)
if sort_id in sort_by.keys():
    sort = sort_by[sort_id]
    sort = sort.desc() if order == 'desc' else sort.asc()
    query = query.order_by(sort)
query = query.filter(Product.has_offers == True)
products = query.paginate(page=page, per_page=50)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried doing this but it only gives me one `Product`:

You must be using MySQL 5.6 or older, since newer versions will not accept that query and raise an error:

```
ERROR 3029 (HY000): Expression #1 of ORDER BY contains aggregate function and applies to the result of a non-aggregated query
```

See the answers in ["What can an aggregate function do in the ORDER BY clause?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099282/what-can-an-aggregate-function-do-in-the-order-by-clause) for an explanation as to why you are getting one `Product` as a result.

Your original approach is not that far from a working solution in the end. All you need to do is to add a suitable `GROUP BY` clause that produces deterministic results in your query for it to work correctly:

```
order_op = desc if order == 'desc' else asc

query = db.session.query(Product).\
    join(Product.offers).\
    filter(Product.has_offers).\
    group_by(Product.id).\
    order_by(order_op(func.count()))

products = query.paginate(page=page, per_page=50)
```

The selected columns are [determined by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency) `Product.id`, so you don't get indeterminate results.

Comment: Thank you. That worked! I am using the latest version of MariaDB